# Make my phone with Windows 10 Mobile able to recognize apps in SD

Tags: insider-preview, windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-820

Yesterday I updated my Nokia Lumia 820 from Windows Phone 8.1 to Windows 10 Mobile Technical preview (insider preview release, build 10586). Before doing that, I had re-installed the OS.

Now my phone doesn't recognize apps still saved in SD (that I used with 8.1). **How can I make my phone able to recognize those apps as its apps?**

Indeed, if I try to change where the phone has to save new apps, from current device to SD it says that in SD unit there are of another device.

Here the message:

> Delete other apps?
>
> This drive has apps from another device. To use this drive, the other apps must first be deleted. Do you want to continue?
>
> Yes/ No

**Are there any possibilities to do that**, or I have to delete those apps? Referred to the message, is there the risk of delete also photos in SD?

Comment: As my knowledge every app you install on SD Card, it stores small files like Tiles, Tile name, SD Card reference(s) etc. in device phone storage, so if you insert SD Card from another device, you need to delete other apps of old devices stored at SD Card.

Comment: if you select yes in message, it will delete only data of Apps from SD Card, it will not delete photos or videos or any personal files.

Comment: Thanks. My doubt was if there is any bug in the process described in the message. I'll try.

Comment: you said you re-installed OS. You need to delete older app data. You will not have old apps that was in your previous OS.

Comment: I have done, no errors.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no ways to get those apps back.
As you've re-installed OS, you need to download those apps from store.

*Solution of photos being deleted* :
your files other than app data are **safe**, but you can **Remove SD Card** and then delete those apps(in case if you don't want any risk).

Comment: That's correct, the phone encrypts the data on the card which is nice and secure but a pain when you change OS or change phones. I no longer recommend putting apps on an SD card in WP as it is too easy for them to be wiped or corrupted if you have to pull the battery.